# Django | How to reference the User's username when using OneToOneField in UserProfile?

Tags: python, django

Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Userprofile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    username = user.__unicode__()
    path = './data/'+username+'/'
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=path)
    labelfile = models.FileField(upload_to=path, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.user.username


def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Userprofile.objects.create(user=instance)


post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

the problem is:

```
AttributeError: 'OneToOneField' object has no attribute 'model'
```

I want a file upload function that it can save in a index related to the User's name, but I can't find a good way to do it. And I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: You should define function to create path and pass it to `upload_to`. There are already many questions and answers on this.

Comment: The title for this question has nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: @Rohan Sorry...but could you give me some questions and answers? I am a noob and this is my first time to here. so I am not familiar with using this website and asking question.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Fine...I'm really not good at it, and I will keep learning...but thanks for your advise~